# Good books and lecture notes to learn pseudo-differential operators and spectral theory

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation, spectral-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

I am looking for a list of good books and lecture notes to learn pseudo-differential operators and spectral theory (for infinite dimensions.)

I am familiar with introductory functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and Fourier Analysis. Books inclined towards partial differential equations is a plus. In particular, I intend to study fractional Laplacian operators.

Edit: Please note that it need not be a single book covering both the topics.

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of applications you have in mind? And it would be good to include your background.

Comment: It should be a good idea to add the [tag:pseudo-differential-operators] tag, perhaps [tag:functional-analysis] can be removed to make space? [This search result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-differential-operators+reference-request) may be useful in the future

Comment: Why is this question closed? How can I improve it? It have mentioned my relevant background and also why I want to study those topics?

Comment: The microlocal analysis tag is also very relevant here, but I'm not sure which to remove in favor of it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this graduate text text:

*Spectral theory of linear differential operators and comparison algebras*
By Heinz Otto Cordes, Cordes Heinz Otto · 1987

I think this book covers every topic you mentioned.

https://books.google.com/books?id=6WlLjznD2zwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=heinz+otto+cordes&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8zJeg6cz2AhVbm2oFHaMcDRkQ6AF6BAgLEAI

Comment: Thanks! This indeed covers the topics I have mentioned. I will however wait for other answers before accepting an answer. There are certainly more than one good books on these topics!

Answer (score 1):

For some references with specific material on both spectral theory and $\Psi$DO's, see

1. Shubin's book "Pseudodifferential Operators and Spectral Theory" sounds perfect for you.
2. Michael Taylor's 2nd PDE book contains two large chapters on both topics. He also has a more extensive textbook on pseudodifferential operators and nonlinear PDE.
3. Dimassi and Sjostrand's "Spectral Asymptotics in the Semi-Classical Limit" covers both.
4. Grigis and Sjostrand's "Microlocal Analysis for Differential Operators: An Introduction" covers both.
5. Zworski's "Semiclassical Analysis" covers both and has many applications to PDE theory.

Also, see [Textbook/monograph for microlocal analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834002/textbook-monograph-for-microlocal-analysis/3374328#3374328).